# Como fazer um NOT IN mysql com 2 tabelas

Tags: mysql, sql

Tenho 3 tabelas Pessoa, turma_materia, Notas, tabela pessoa tem:

```
+------+--------------+-----------+
| id   |  Nome        |  turma    |
+------+--------------+-----------+
| 1    | Aluno 01     | 1         |
| 2    | Aluno 02     | 2         |
```

Na tabela turma_materia tem:

```
+------+--------+---------+
| id   |  turma | materia |
+------+--------+---------+
| 1    |  1     |  1      |
| 2    |  2     |  1      |
| 3    |  2     |  2      |
```

Na tabela nota preciso inserir o aluno e a matéria vinculado a turma do aluno onde não tem na tabela notas.
 Resumindo, irá verificar se já tem a materia para aquele aluno, se não tiver irá adicionar.

Se fosse com uma tabela seria assim:

```
SELECT PE.id, PE.nome, TM.materia
FROM pessoa PE
LEFT JOIN turma_materia TM ON PE.turma=TM.turma
WHERE TM.materia NOT IN (SELECT nota_materia FROM nota)
```

**Acrescentando:** A tabela nota tem

```
+------+----------+-----------+-------+------+-------+------+
| id   |  Aluno   |  Materia  |  UNI  | UNII | UNIII | UNIV |
+------+----------+-----------+-------+------+-------+------+
| 1    |  1       |   1       |  NULL | NULL | NULL  | NULL |
```

Comment: Você quer filtrar os ALUNOS que tem registro de TURMA e MATERIA, mas não tem NOTA ? Aí depois para inserir nota, você já sabe ? Só precisa do select ?

Comment: na verdade eu quero inserir na tabela nota o aluno e a materia se não consta os dois juntos na tabela nota, mas estou com dúvidas só como verificar isto.Exemplo na tabela tem aluno 2 e materia 1, mas não tem o aluno 2 e materia 2, então ele vai mostrar que não tem esta materia para este aluno

Comment: cade a tabela nota ?

Comment: Eu ia dizer exatamente isso. Falta você postar a tabela nota, onde tem as ligações necessárias.

Comment: Na tabela nota tem:
 ID  |   aluno  |  materia | UNI | UNII | UNIII | UNIV

ai preciso só inserir o aluno e a materia, o restante pode ser nulo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Que tal alterar o modelo do seu banco de dados para simplificar sua vida ?!

Reparei que seu problema possui 4 entidades distintas: `Aluno`, `Materia`, `Turma` e `Nota`.

Essas 4 entidades podem ser representas da seguinte forma:

```
-- MATERIAS
CREATE TABLE tb_materia
(
   id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
   descricao TEXT NOT NULL
 );

-- TURMAS
CREATE TABLE tb_turma
(
  id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
  descricao TEXT NOT NULL
);

-- ALUNOS
CREATE TABLE tb_aluno
(
  id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
  nome TEXT NOT NULL,
  id_turma BIGINT
);

-- NOTAS
CREATE TABLE tb_nota
(
   id_materia BIGINT NOT NULL,
   id_aluno BIGINT NOT NULL,
   UNI REAL,
   UNII REAL,
   UNIII REAL,
   UNIV REAL,
   PRIMARY KEY( id_materia, id_aluno )
 );
```

Agora, Vamos aos relacionamentos:

```
-- ALUNOS -> TURMA (UM aluno possui NENHUMA ou APENAS UMA turma)
ALTER TABLE tb_aluno ADD FOREIGN KEY (id_turma) REFERENCES tb_turma;

-- NOTA -> ALUNO (UMA nota possui obrigatoriamente APENAS UM aluno)
ALTER TABLE tb_nota ADD FOREIGN KEY (id_aluno) REFERENCES tb_aluno;

-- NOTA -> MATERIA (UMA nota possui obrigatoriamente APENAS UMA materia)
ALTER TABLE tb_nota ADD FOREIGN KEY (id_materia) REFERENCES tb_materia;
```

Cadastrando Dados:

```
-- CADASTRO DAS MATERIAS
INSERT INTO tb_materia ( id, descricao ) VALUES ( 1, 'PORTUGUES' );
INSERT INTO tb_materia ( id, descricao ) VALUES ( 2, 'MATEMATICA' );
INSERT INTO tb_materia ( id, descricao ) VALUES ( 3, 'HISTORIA' );

-- CADASTRO DAS TURMAS
INSERT INTO tb_turma ( id, descricao ) VALUES ( 1, '3-A' );
INSERT INTO tb_turma ( id, descricao ) VALUES ( 2, '2-A' );
INSERT INTO tb_turma ( id, descricao ) VALUES ( 3, '1-B' );

-- CADASTRO DOS ALUNOS
INSERT INTO tb_aluno ( id, nome, id_turma ) VALUES ( 1, 'JOAO', 1 );
INSERT INTO tb_aluno ( id, nome, id_turma ) VALUES ( 2, 'MARIA', 1 );
INSERT INTO tb_aluno ( id, nome, id_turma ) VALUES ( 3, 'JESUS', 2 );

-- CADASTRO DE NOTAS (SOMENTE JESUS do 2-A)
INSERT INTO tb_nota ( id_aluno, id_materia, UNI, UNII, UNIII, UNIV ) VALUES ( 3, 1, 9.0, 8.5, 5.5, 1.4 );
INSERT INTO tb_nota ( id_aluno, id_materia, UNI, UNII, UNIII, UNIV ) VALUES ( 3, 2, 8.5, 4.5, 6.5, 5.2 );
INSERT INTO tb_nota ( id_aluno, id_materia, UNI, UNII, UNIII, UNIV ) VALUES ( 3, 3, 3.0, 9.5, 2.5, 9.4 );
```

Agora vamos a consulta que recupera todos os `Alunos` e `Materias` indepenentes das `Notas` cadastradas:

```
SELECT
    m.descricao AS "Materia",
    a.nome AS "Nome do Aluno",
    t.descricao AS "Turma",
    n.UNI,
    n.UNII,
    n.UNIII,
    n.UNIV
FROM
  tb_aluno AS a
CROSS JOIN
  tb_materia AS m
LEFT JOIN
  tb_nota AS n ON ( n.id_aluno = a.id AND n.id_materia = m.id )
LEFT JOIN
  tb_turma AS t ON ( t.id = a.id_turma )
```

Saída:

```
|    Materia | Nome do Aluno | Turma |    uni |   unii |  uniii |   univ |
|------------|---------------|-------|--------|--------|--------|--------|
|  PORTUGUES |          JOAO |   3-A | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) |
|  PORTUGUES |         MARIA |   3-A | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) |
|  PORTUGUES |         JESUS |   2-A |      9 |    8.5 |    5.5 |    1.4 |
| MATEMATICA |          JOAO |   3-A | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) |
| MATEMATICA |         MARIA |   3-A | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) |
| MATEMATICA |         JESUS |   2-A |    8.5 |    4.5 |    6.5 |    5.2 |
|   HISTORIA |          JOAO |   3-A | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) |
|   HISTORIA |         MARIA |   3-A | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) |
|   HISTORIA |         JESUS |   2-A |      3 |    9.5 |    2.5 |    9.4 |
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/cd898

Answer (score 4):

Fazendo por partes. Primeiro identificamos pares aluno-notas que não existem na tabela Nota. Tem várias formas, fica aqui uma possível alternativa:

```
SELECT PE.id, PE.nome, TM.materia
  FROM pessoa PE
 INNER JOIN turma_materia TM
    ON TM.turma = PE.turma
  LEFT JOIN nota NT
    ON NT.Aluno = PE.Id
   AND NT.Materia = TM.Materia
 WHERE TM.ID IS NULL   -- Combinação Aluno/Materia não existe na tabela Nota
```

Fica apenas a falta o INSERT na tabela Nota, que pode ser feito assim:

```
INSERT INTO Nota(Aluno, Materia)
SELECT PE.id, TM.materia
  FROM pessoa PE
 INNER JOIN turma_materia TM
    ON TM.turma = PE.turma
  LEFT JOIN nota NT
    ON NT.Aluno = PE.Id
   AND NT.Materia = TM.Materia
 WHERE TM.ID IS NULL
```

Como detalhado no comentário, apenas o aluno e a matéria são inseridos na tabela Nota, os restantes assumem o valor default da tabela.

Fica aqui o link para o [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5e7412/10). Neste exemplo, a tabela Nota apenas tem informação referente ao "Aluno 01", pelo que a instrução de SELECT irá devolver todas as matérias em que "Aluno 02" se matriculou.